# Servlet file upload: Image file adding long number to file name in upload dir

Tags: jsp, servlets, file-upload

I am setting up a simple local webpage which involves uploading images to a file location on my local computer. The problem I am having is that when the file is saved to the location, it adds a long number to the end of the file name. I have the paths saved to a local sql server so this will not work, can anyone tell me how to get the file uploaded using the name without the long number at the end?

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    FileItemFactory itemFactory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
    ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(itemFactory);
    upload.setHeaderEncoding("UTF-8");

    try {
        List<FileItem> items = upload.parseRequest(new ServletRequestContext(request));

        for (FileItem item : items) {
            response.setContentType("text/html");
            String contentType = item.getContentType();
            String fileName = item.getName();
            String fieldName = item.getFieldName();
            String title = item.getName();
            String[] parts =  fileName.split("\\\\");
            fileName = parts[parts.length-1];

            if (!contentType.equals("image/png")) {
                request.setAttribute("message", "Only png format image files supported");
                request.getRequestDispatcher("/loggedInUser.jsp").forward(request, response);
            } else {
                File uploadDir = new File("C:\\Users\\dholmes\\workspace\\Upload");

                File file = File.createTempFile(fileName, ".png", uploadDir);
                item.write(file);

                request.setAttribute("message", fileName + " uploaded.");
                request.getRequestDispatcher("/loggedInUser.jsp").forward(request, response);
            }
        }

    } catch (FileUploadException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

So what happens for the following example, I upload a file called Crest.png, goes through the entire process fine, but when I go to the location where it is being saved, it is with something like the following name: Crest.png6893740195830382611

I've spent days looking for a solution, hoping it just needs a fresh pair of eyes! Thanks a million!

Comment: Is there already a file called Crest.png in that directory?

Comment: There is not.. I think it's related to the temp file directory creation and it adds the session ID to the end of the file name before saving it